# Python 2 Javascript (Pako) decompress error

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, zlib

Trying to compress string in the server (python/zlib), send data to client (websockets) and decompress via pako. Compression, sending and receiving data is ok. But I cant decompress the blob.

Here is the python (server-side) code. Sending to client via websocket:

`sock.write_message(zlib.compress("some text"), binary=True)`

Here is client code (javascript, for decompress using pako):

```
g_Socket.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log(e.data); //Blob
    var result = pako.inflate(e.data, { to: 'string' });
```

The error is: pako.js:787 Uncaught unknown compression method

Any help please =(

Comment: can you show us what you're getting in the console (`e.data`) even if it's binary?

Comment: Here it is: http://imgbox.com/UPzDl3UI

Comment: can you try `zlib.compress("some text",0)` ? it does not compress at 0. Then change to 1, ...

Comment: So I need to get the plain text in blob with compress level 0?

Comment: Well, here it is in compress level 0: http://imgbox.com/56T0WKJu

Comment: no, it was just a minimal try. Does it work with level 0? (default is level 6). Then you can ramp up to level 1, 2, etc..

Comment: Please provide `e.data` in hex. Then we can see if it is a zlib stream or not, and if it made the journey intact.